# C++ Functions and strange errors

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-errors, logic

So I'm writing a small Rock, Paper, Scissors game structure in C++ and I've run into some errors I don't understand.

### Solution

The function `string numberToWord (int x)` can't be in the function main. It has to be a separate method due to the way the compiler works. I simply moved it out then it worked fine.

### Previous Question

So I'm writing a small Rock, Paper, Scissors game structure in C++ and I've run into some errors I don't understand.

The first is the code expects a ';' at the NumberToWord function but it shouldn't since it's a function.

Another error is randomly one of the else statements it doesn't seem to like.

Maybe I'm missing something, I don't know but it should be a simple fix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int seed = static_cast <int> (time(0)); //Sets the random seed
    srand(seed);

    int winCount = 0;

    string numberToWord (int x) {
        string outputChoice;

        if (x == 0) { outputChoice = "Rock"; }
        else if (x == 1) { outputChoice = "Paper"; }
        else if (x == 2) { outputChoice = "Scissors"; }

        return outputChoice;
    }

    while (winCount < 3) {
        int computerChoice = rand() % 4;
        int userChoice;

        cout << userChoice << endl;

        cout << "Please Enter 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper, or 2 for Scissors: "; //Asks for user input
        cin >> userChoice; //Inputs user input to variable

        if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "Draw!" << endl;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 1) && (computerChoice == 2)) { //Rock v Paper
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "Compuer wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 1) && (computerChoice == 3)) { //Rock v Scissors
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You win!" << endl;
            winCount += 1;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 2) && (computerChoice == 1)) { //Paper v Rock
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You win!" << endl;
            winCount += 1;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 2) && (computerChoice == 3)) { //Paper v Scissors
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "Compuer wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 3) && (computerChoice == 1)) { //Scissors v Rock
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "Compuer wins!" << endl;
        }
        else if ((userChoice == 3) && (computerChoice == 2)) { //Scissors v Paper
            cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You Choose: " << numberToWord(userChoice) << endl;
            cout << "You win!" << endl;
            winCount += 1;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help!

[image: Errors]

---

Part 2

Simply put the program doesn't like the '<<'. I use this just fine in many other programs for variables but this time when I used a string variable it throws an error. I looked up C++ string variables and it looks like I'm doing it correctly so I don't know the reason for the errors.

References:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

```
void displayOutput(int comp, int user, string winner) {
    string compOutputChoice = "";
    string userOutputChoice = "";

    /*
    if (comp == 0) { compOutputChoice = "Rock"; }
    else if (comp == 1) { compOutputChoice = "Paper"; }
    else if (comp == 2) { compOutputChoice = "Scissors"; }

    if (user == 0) { userOutputChoice = "Rock"; }
    else if (user == 1) { userOutputChoice = "Paper"; }
    else if (user == 2) { userOutputChoice = "Scissors"; }
    */

    cout << "Compuer Choose: " << compOutputChoice << endl;
    cout << "You Choose: " << userOutputChoice << endl;
    //cout << winner << endl;

    return;
}
```

Errors:

Error (active)      no operator "<<" 32

Error (active)      no operator "<<" 33

Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 32

Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 33

Comment: You should post the error messages verbatim in your question - as **text**, *not* image.

Comment: You cannot define another function inside of the `main()` functions body, unless its a lambda expression.

Comment: That solves one problem, however I still cant use the function in line with cout >> to output it

Comment: @Rext `>>` is for input, you probably mean `<<` for output ;-)

Comment: You ask for 0 based input and computes them as if they were 1 based. Using `rand() % 4` is wrong as it leaves 4 options to you, not three...

Comment: Jesper Juhl, sorry I miss typed, I am using << but it still throws an error :( Thanks for the heads up Gabriel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `string numberToWord (int x)` is nested inside the `main` function. That is not valid C++.

The GCC compiler *does* support nested functions as an extension, but it's not part of the standard and other compilers (that I know of) don't accept it. Just don't do that. Move the function out of `main` (or, if it makes sense, make it a lambda).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple. numberToWord cannot be an internal function of main.  Move it outside main or change it to a lambda if you are using a newer C++.

```
auto numberToWord = [](int x) -> string {
    string outputChoice;

    if (x == 0) { outputChoice = "Rock"; }
    else if (x == 1) { outputChoice = "Paper"; }
    else if (x == 2) { outputChoice = "Scissors"; }

    return outputChoice;
};
```

Comment: Only problem now is I still can't use:

Comment: cout << "Compuer Choose: " << numberToWord(computerChoice) << endl;

Comment: @rext, what do you mean "still can't use."  What does not work for you?

Comment: so sorry I'm new to this site so my formatting sucks, I edited my post and its under part 2, hopefully that makes sense